# Can't get 'distance_meters' field from react-native-google-places-autocomplete query

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

In the documentation for the Google API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete), it says that if you use the 'origin' param with a (latitude, longitude) value, it should return the field 'distance_meters'.

When I put the api call into my browser (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Ar&types=establishment&origin=40.70823656815506,-73.94331559793082&key=<API_KEY>) I do get the 'distance_meters' field, as you can see at the bottom of the image.

[image]

However, when I add the same params into the 'query' prop of the GooglePlacesAutocomplete component in react-native, I only get back a few of the fields shown above, and I do not get the 'distance_meters' field.

[image]

Please advise me on how to get the 'distance_meters' field using the GooglePlacesAutocomplete field. My code is below, I am console logging the rowData from renderRow.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you check the [GooglePlacesAutocomplete.d.ts source file](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/v2.0.0/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.d.ts) of the react-native-google-places-autocomplete library, scroll to see the `interface Query` and you will notice that the `origin` parameter is not yet included in the library

```
// @see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
interface Query<T = AutocompleteRequestType> {
  key: string;
  sessiontoken?: string;
  offset?: number;
  location?: string;
  radius?: number;
  language?: Language;
  components?: string;
  rankby?: string;
  type?: T;
  strictbounds?: boolean;
  // deprecated. see https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/pull/384
  types?: T;
}
```

In addition, to see all the Autocomplete predictions results, you can use the `renderDescription` function and log the data since this function determines the data passed to each renderRow (search result).

`renderDescription={(data) => console.log(data)}`

Here's a [sample code](https://snack.expo.io/DxHyQEp3s) where you will see that the `distance_meters` is not returned since the `origin` parameter is not defined in the Query interface.

You can file the issue on the github repository [here](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues).